# Sublime Text 2 - Drop Cursor From Multiple Line Selection

Tags: sublimetext2

I've been using ST2 for a while now and am curious if there is a way to select multiple lines and drop the top or bottom selection.

For instance, if we selected four of them and then, drop the top cursor, I'd only have three selections. This would be very helpful when I'm doing multi-line edits with slightly different data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the ST console `` ctrl+` `` and write `del view.sel()[0]` to delete the first and `del view.sel()[-1]` to delete the last selection. You can obviously adapt the number to delete an other selection.

An alternative is to install [MultiEditUtils](https://github.com/philippotto/Sublime-MultiEditUtils#use-selections-as-fields) with "selection fields", which is written to slightly modify single selections while working with multiple selections. Add the keybindings:

```js
// default use of selection_fields
{ "keys": ["alt+d"], "command": "selection_fields" },
// add the current selections as a fields
{ "keys": ["alt+a"], "command": "selection_fields", "args": {"mode": "add"} },
// jump and remove current selection in selection_fields
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+d"], "command": "selection_fields",
  "args": {"mode": "smart", "only_other": true} },
// cancel selection_fields and remove current selection
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+d"], "command": "selection_fields",
  "args": {"mode": "toggle", "only_other": true} },
```

Afterwards you can press `alt+d` to change the selections to "fields". Now move with `tab` or `shift+tab` to the selection you want to remove. Press `ctrl+alt+d` to remove the selection and jump to the next field. Press `ctrl+alt+shift+d` to remove the selection and convert *all other* fields to selections. Press `escape` to convert *all* fields to selections.

Comment: Thank you! This is a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using subtractive drag select. On Windows and Linux, hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> (on OS X, hold down <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>) while holding down mouse button 1 (typically the left mouse button, for right-handed users) and dragging across the cursor, either from left to right or right to left - the drag needs to start in the editing area, though, not the gutter to the left of the text where the line numbers are. Subtractive select also works when selecting words, lines, or columns - just hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> while double- or triple-clicking, or selecting columns.

For a full list of available mouse combinations, go to your `Packages` folder, the one opened when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**, go to the `Default` folder, and open `Default (YourOSHere).sublime-mousemap` (`YourOSHere` being one of `Windows`, `Linux`, or `OSX`) with JSON syntax highlighting. If you're using Sublime Text 3 (which I ***very strongly*** recommend [upgrading](https://sublimetext.com/3) to), you'll need to install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer), as the files in `Default` are now in a `.sublime-package` archive. Once installed, select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`, scroll down to `Default`, then select the `.sublime-mousemap` file that corresponds to your operating system.

Comment: This works but is it possible to do it without using the mouse?

Comment: @PPJN no, unfortunately it does not. Think about it: if you have multiple cursors, all of which are responding to arrow commands, how are you going to pick an arbitrary one of those cursors and delete it, without using the mouse?